# Failed to get a JSON response using the requests module

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to get a JSON response from this [webpage](https://clutch.co/developers) by running the script below. Every time I run the script, I get status code ***403***. I can see the data within the json content when I navigate to this [link](https://clutch.co/directory/facets?sort_by=Sponsorship&path=%2Fdevelopers&nonce=MvUtFcRmUautzeQV&page=1&mask=false) manually, though.

```
import requests

url = 'https://clutch.co/developers'
link = 'https://clutch.co/directory/facets'

headers = {
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,bn;q=0.8',
    'referer': 'https://clutch.co/developers',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

params = {
    'sort_by': 'Sponsorship',
    'path': '/developers',
    'nonce': 'MvUtFcRmUautzeQV',
    'page': '1',
    'mask': 'false'
}

resp = requests.get(link,params=params,headers=headers)
print(resp.status_code)
print(resp.json())
```

Comment: Do you know what HTTP 403 means?

Comment: It looks like the website is blocking your request due to the fact that it doesn't recognize your User Agent. Try changing the User Agent to a more common one (like Chrome or Firefox). You may also want to include additional headers in your request, such as a cookie or an authorization header.

Comment: Yes, I know @Fred. I tried sending the requests through a VPN, but it didn't work either.

Comment: @MITHU The site you're trying to access is "protected" by Cloudflare. You might want to use some other module other than *requests* - e.g., *cloudscraper*

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the *cloudscraper* module. This can bypass Cloudflare for the URL you're interested in.

```
python -m pip install cloudscraper
```

Then:

```
import cloudscraper

params = {
    'sort_by': 'Sponsorship',
    'path': '/developers',
    'nonce': 'MvUtFcRmUautzeQV',
    'page': '1',
    'mask': 'false'
}

scraper = cloudscraper.CloudScraper()

(r := scraper.get('https://clutch.co/directory/facets', params=params)).raise_for_status()
```